# Android 13 and 14 Recording Notification Exclusions for Children's School

Tags: android, android-notifications

Small non-profit that cares for high risk children uses stealth recording software on company owned cell phones that stay on the property to protect the kids.  They have legal right etc.  Cannot find a way to disable the constant notifications now showing anytime a screenshot is taken or sounds are recorded.  Many hours online to Samsung already.  Can anyone point me in a different direction?

Software developers used the following and it works temporarily but notifiers come back everytime phone is restarted:

adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled true default
adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default

Comment: I would say stackoverflow is probably not the site you're looking for here, perhaps [superuser](https://superuser.com)? That command looks like it would be a runtime change (and I wouldn't expect it to persist through a reboot). You could very likely disable those notifications for the app directly in android settings however.

Comment: TYSM.  I appreciate the help.